# Enabling Azure Storage CORS rule via Azure CLI

Tags: azure-storage, azure-cli2

I'm trying to configure CORS on my storage account with the Azure CLI 2.0, and I keep getting an error.

Command:

`az storage cors add --connection-string $connstr --origins '*' --methods GET --allowed-headers 'x-ms-meta-abc,content-type,x-ms-blob-type,x-ms-meta-data*,x-ms-meta-target*' --exposed-headers 'x-ms-meta-*' --max-age 200 --services blob`

Output:

> XML specified is not syntactically valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out this is due to very poor error messages from the Storage commands. You get an XML error if there are already 5 CORS rules defined on the storage account.

If you don't run into the XML error, the command above will print a Python stacktrace, because the command requies `--services b` instead of `--services blob`.

The solution is to clear all CORS rules first, then add the new one:

```
az storage cors clear --services b --connection-string $connstr
az storage cors add --connection-string $connstr --origins '*' --methods GET --allowed-headers 'x-ms-meta-abc,content-type,x-ms-blob-type,x-ms-meta-data*,x-ms-meta-target*' --exposed-headers 'x-ms-meta-*' --max-age 200 --services blob
```

Answer (score 0):

As **lindydonna - msft** mentioned that we need to use `--services b` instead of `--services blob`. If we want to add cors for multiple services we could combine **bfqt**.

> The storage service(s) for which to add the CORS rule: (b)lob (f)ile (q)ueue (t)able. Can be combined.

We could get more detail info about [azure storage cors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing--CORS--Support-for-the-Azure-Storage-Services?redirectedfrom=MSDN) and  `az storage cors add` from [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/cors#add).